# How get long long value from sqlite3_stmt sqlite3 in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, long-integer, sqldatatypes

I want to get a `long long`data type value from `sqlite3` in iOS from some table.

If I want get the standard `int` value I currently use the `sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1)` function.

But how can I get a larger value if I save there a `long long` data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3_column_int64()`.